# Flag review collapse/uncollapse icon has the wrong state

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderator-tools

In the flag review tab of the moderator tools when I uncollapse, that is expand an item and take an action, like flagging or casting a close vote on it, then it automatically collapses again. However the state of the collapse/uncollapse icon doesn't get updated.

I've taken some screenshots (with freehand circles, aw yea!).

This is how it looks after either flagging or casting a close vote on a question.

[image: collapsed item with wrong icon]

Here is a screenshot of the uncollapsed item.

[image: uncollapsed item with wrong icon]

It is nothing dramatic but I thought you should know.

Comment: nice catch .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue with the current moderator tools. If the issue remains for you, please let me know!